# TextMate force correct indentation

Tags: python, emacs, editor, indentation, textmate

I'm learning Python and I've been using Emacs as my editor. Now I'm switching to TextMate, it seems a lot more modern and offers a lot of convenience. However, I do miss one feature from Emacs where it forces the correct indentation. For example, when I break a long line of code into multiple lines, it automatically indent to the correct location, and it doesn't allow you to indent to any arbitrary location with the tab key. I found this particularly useful for Python coding where styling is important. Is there a way to achieve the same thing in TextMate?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use **sublime txt** it's the best editor i used http://www.sublimetext.com/3

it's good with indentation

Good luck